# QueryDsl - Create a predicate to check if localdate is part of the current week

Tags: java, querydsl

My goal is to check if a LocalDate is part of the current week.
Similar examples for year and month
startDate.month().eq(LocalDate.now().getMonthValue());
startDate.year().eq(LocalDate.now().getYear());

Ex 1 : 10 - Jun - 2021 (current day) is part if the 7 Jun - 13 Jun.
Ex 2 : 6 - Jun - 2021 is not part of the current week.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```java
date.year().eq(DateExpression.currentDate().year())
   .and(date.week().eq(DateExpression.currentDate().week()))
```

Comment: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function week(date) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Any suggestions?

Comment: When using PostgreSQL, make sure to use `PostgreSQLTemplates` with your queries  so that the appropiate SQL is being generated: https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/blob/master/querydsl-sql/src/main/java/com/querydsl/sql/PostgreSQLTemplates.java#L117